# Android - Creating JsonFactory causes app crash

Tags: java, android, json, google-api

I ran into a bit of trouble creating an app for android, I want to use a JsonFactory but the app crashes the moment I create one.

I imported:

```
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
```

And then I used:

```
private static final JsonFactory factory = new JacksonFactory();
```

I also added the "google-http-client-jackson2-1.16.0-rc.jar" and the "google-http-client-1.16.0-rc.jar" libraries to the build path.

So both the emulator and the physical device gives "Unfortunately, ##apname## has stopped"

Logcat gives the following:

```
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.<init>(JacksonFactory.java:45)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  at com.example.youtubesearch.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:42)
08-29 13:28:27.754: E/AndroidRuntime(990):  ... 15 more
08-29 13:28:27.764: W/ActivityManager(288):   Force finishing activity com.example.youtubesearch/.MainActivity
```

Help would be much appreciated!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the exact error message? We need some stack trace to help.

Comment: The console displays no error so I don't know how to get the stack trace

Comment: @user2728764 - in what console are you looking for this? Isn't there anything in the `LogCat` - it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is rather simple:

From the logcat you can see the following is missing:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
```

So I just added [this](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core&version=2.0.2&searchType=bundlesByClass&searchQuery=json&showAll=true) to my build path

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time